# Why does Angular automatically invoke setTimeout in one instance vs. another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Apologies if this sounds strange, but I'll try to describe what's happening as best I can.  We were provided a small service that provides a single form UI that we capture the results of via an event.  We've integrated this into two applications and we're seeing some different behavior when we load the UI in a modal window via an iframe.  When integrated into one UI it loads pretty quickly.  However, in the other UI it takes several seconds to load.  Now, the only difference I could find is that setTimeout is being triggered sever seconds after the model is created.  I discovered this using the Firefox development tools in the Performance tab.

Now, I believe that the UI for this form is built in a non-recent version of Angular (AngularJS?) based on some Google searches using strings that I could see in a minimized polyfill.xxxx.js file.  However, I can't understand the code that was minimized and I have no version information to help me get back to a version that I can try to read and understand.

I did testing using the Performance API before the iframe is created in case the issue was something in my code, but the tested code is finished in < 100ms, so that didn't appear to be the issue.  It's not a network issue as the requests occur pretty quickly.  Also, both applications are referencing the same instance, so the only difference is the app that it's integrated into.

So, my primary question is what could be causing Angular (AngularJs) to set a timeout on page load?  My secondary question is what advice is there for trying to debug this?  I don't use Angular at all, so I'm not even sure where to begin outside of what I've already tried.  The only custom app code I see looks to be Angular configuration/properties, so no JavaScript to debug.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice with `setTimeout()` in such a situation is to not use any `setTimeout()`.

I ran into same situation not only angular most of the framework treat `setTimeout()` a bit differently.

What I mean `setTimeout()` in a plain JS app and angularJS app and Angular App will differ the time interval.

`setTimeout()` is set to execute after a certain time, but that's is not guaranteed by the thread.
Some time angular completing change detection and watcher life cycle, all mingle with `setTimeout()` and you will end up with strange behavior.

So better not to use that unless you are sure it's not gonna mingle with other running things.

Please share the code snippet if possible

Comment: From my end, there's not much of a code snippet: <iframe src="someurl" style="..." height="600px"/>

Regarding where setTimeout is being called, the only place I found it was in the polyfill file that I mentioned in my original question.  And no, I'm not calling it at all in this case.  The problem is I don't know what/how it's being called.